# Discussion of $f_n(x) = n\log(x) - x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, estimation

At first I had to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_{n}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x} dx = \frac{1}{2}$

Using stirlings formula and appropriate substitution I have shown the above. I now have to discuss the function $f_{n}(x) = n \log(x) - x, \;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Using $f_n(x)$ I want to find useful estimations for:

$\int_{n}^{n+n^\alpha}x^ne^{-x} dx $ and $\int_{n+n^\alpha}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x} dx $ for an appropriate $\alpha <1 $

I can't figure out how the above defined $f_n(x)$ should help me to find proper estimations for the given integrals.

Could someone give me a hint?
That would be very nice!

Thomas

Comment: $x^n e^{-x} = e^{f_n(x)}$.

Comment: I got now an estimation for the first integral for $x \in (n,n+n^\alpha)$, which is $n^{n+\alpha}*e^{-n*(1+n^{\alpha-1})}<= integral <= n^{n+\alpha}*(1+n^{\alpha -1})*e^{-n}$, but I cannot tell how $\alpha < 1$ should help me and I'm also stuck with the second integral?
Could you help me again? I don't know where this should lead me.

Answer (score 1):

We shall first examine the integral $I_n$, given by

$$\begin{align}I_n&=\int_0^n x^ne^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{n} e^{f_n(x)}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $f_n(x)=n\log(x)-x$.

Enforcing the substitution $x\to (n-x)/\sqrt{2n}$ in $(1)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\sqrt{2n}\int_0^{\sqrt{n/2}} e^{f_n\left(\frac{n-x}{\sqrt{2n}}\right)}\,dx\\\\
&=\sqrt{2n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n\int_0^{\sqrt{n/2}} e^{-x^2}e^{g_n(x)}\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

where $g_n(x)=n\left(\log\left(1-x/\sqrt{n/2}\right)+x/\sqrt{n/2}\right)+x^2$.

---

At this point, we note that $g_n(x)\le 0$ for $x\in [0,\sqrt{n/2})$.  Therefore, $e^{g_n(x)}\le 1$ for $x\in [0,\sqrt{n/2})$.  Moreover, for $x\in (0,\sqrt{n/2})$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{g_n(x)}=1$$

Applying the dominated convergence theorem, we find

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{\sqrt{n/2}} e^{-x^2}e^{g_n(x)}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(e^{g_n(x)}\xi_{[0,\sqrt{n/2}]}(x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}/2\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Divinding $(2)$ by $n!$, applyng Stirling's formula, and using $(3)$ yields the result reported in the OP

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n!}\int_0^n x^n e^{-x}\,dx=\frac12$$

---

MORE TO COME

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

We did something similar to this in our exercises, but we didn't discuss why one needs to split up the integral from $n$ to $n^\alpha$. For the integral of $n^\alpha$ to infinity, we substituted $x=t+n$ and used then the estimation $1+\frac{t}{n} <= 2^{\frac{t}{n}}$ to show the limit is zero. Can you tell me why I cannot to this between $n$ and $n^\alpha$?

Comment: So we had $\frac{1}{n!} \int_n^\infty x^n*e^{-x} dx = \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^\infty (n+t)^n*e^{-(t+n)} dt = \frac{n^n}{n!} * e^{-n} * \int_0^\infty (1+\frac{t}{n})^n * e^{-t} dt$ which is, for n sufficiently large, approximately (Stirling-formula) $\frac{1}{(2*pi*n)^\frac{1}{2}}* \int_0^\infty (1+\frac{t}{n})^n * e^{-t} dt$ . For the integral from $n$ to $\infty$ we got $I <= \frac{1}{(2*pi*n)^\frac{1}{2}}* \int_0^\infty 2^t * e^{-t} dt$ which goes to zero for n large.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: I'm on holiday and will revert with a repy upon my return.